# Using a bash function from a script

Tags: bash, shell

**What is the right way of assigning the output of `lowercase_last2` to another variable? What am I doing wrong below?**

I have a shell script `test_lowercase_last.sh` that defines a couple of functions

```
#!/bin/bash

function lowercase_last2() (
    PART2=/"${1##*/}"
    PART1=${1%"$PART2"}
    PART2_LOWER=$(echo "$PART2" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
    echo ${PART1}${PART2_LOWER}
)

function basic() (
    echo "Testing"
)
```

and another script that means to use them

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(basic)
echo $(lowercase_last /home/santiago/Test)
```

But this is what I get

```
$ source test_lowercase_last.sh
$ ./test_bash_func.sh
./test_bash_func.sh: line 2: basic: command not found

./test_bash_func.sh: line 3: lowercase_last: command not found
```

I actually mean to assign the output of `lowercase_last2` to another variable, but I guess once I get this right, it should be straightforward.
Then the question.

Comment: Sourcing functions into your interactive shell doesn't export them to child processes unless you do that explicitly. Which is good; you wouldn't want interactive-shell customization to be able to break random scripts that you run.

Comment: ...so, the right thing is to `source` the library with the functions *in the script that needs those functions*.

Comment: BTW, using a `.sh` extension on a library that's using deliberately POSIX-noncompliant syntax is misleading at best. `function foo() {` is merging the legacy-ksh `function foo {` syntax and the POSIX-compliant `foo() {` syntax in a way that's not compatible with *either* legacy ksh or the POSIX specification.

Comment: ...if you write a *shell library* that uses bash-only syntax, name it with a `.bash` extension. Whereas executables (a category including shell *scripts* as opposed to shell libraries) should have no extension at all; you run `pip`, not `pip.py`; and you run `ls`, not `ls.elf`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - As for the mixing of legacy-ksh and POSIX, what changes would you suggest I introduce?

Comment: I would suggest only using POSIX-compliant function declaration syntax -- `foo() {`, with no preceding `function`; the `function` keyword is supported as part of bash's policy of trying to accept ksh syntax where it can, but it isn't even implemented in a way identical to how ksh works (where `typeset`'s behavior changes based on which function declaration form was used), so one gets not only obvious incompatibilities with POSIX sh, but also subtle incompatibilities with ksh when using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source the library *in the script you use it from*:

```
#!/bin/bash
source test_lowercase_last.sh

echo "$(basic)"
echo "$(lowercase_last /home/santiago/Test)"
```

Unless you use `export -f lowercase_last basic` to export your functions to the environment, they are not automatically inherited by separate shells. (*Subshells* inherit copies of internal state; but those are `fork()`ed with no `exec()` call; when you run a new script, it's across an `exec` boundary, so it doesn't have access to the original process's non-exported variables).

---

By the way -- see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) re: why `echo`'s arguments should always be quoted when non-constant (and, as an aside, the last table in https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete discussing function declaration syntax options).

Comment: I actually mean to source `test_lowercase_last.sh` in `.bashrc`, so the functions are available in all child processes.
So I would add line `export -f lowercase_last basic` in my script, as you suggested...
 (I am not certain the `export` is needed in this case, I will check).

Comment: Writing a script that doesn't work on anyone's account but yours, or after a `sudo` execution that discards environment variables, or after running a non-bash shell that (legally!) discards environment variables that don't translate to valid shell variable names, isn't exactly a principle-of-least-surprise practice.